# How can I create or aquire a large volume of email, for a presentation?

Tags: email, gmail

I am hosting a training webinar where I am going to show people how to set up GMail for maximum productivity, including Priority Inbox, Labeling, and Filters.

I don't want to show them my personal emails, so I am creating dummy accounts.

Does anyone know how I can create/acquire a large volume of mail for these dummy accounts so that I can show the attendees the power of the features?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to some newsletters, competition or lottery games, register at some erotic or dating sites. All of that together will bring you an avalanche of advertising emails. Daily!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IFTTT [Date & Time Channel](https://ifttt.com/date_and_time) to trigger every hour and send an email message.

Answer (score 0):

Post the email in a *very* public place, like Twitter, Reddit, etc.